# Is it posible to clone a branch from tfs to git without some inner directories?

Tags: regex, git-tfs

The git-tfs clone command contains an option named --ignore-regex. I found instructions how to use this command to omit files from the clonning but is it possible to clone a branch from tfs to git and omit entire inner directory of the branch?

If it is possible what is the format of the command?
git tfs clone --ignore-regex= http://myserver:8080/mycollection $\mybranch

Answer (score 1):

```
git tfs --ignore-regex=DirectoryNameToIgnore clone tfs url
```

Here the DirectoryNameToIgnore is present in the root directory.